# Xamarin Android Library Binding - Class does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Play Core (the package for reviews & tasks needed to launch reviews) [split for v2.0.0 into individual packages](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes), so I'm trying to create a Xamarin Android bindings library for the review and tasks. I successfully got tasks working but I am getting this error for the review nuget when it should just work according to their docs. It might be a simple fix, I thought I just had to add these lines in the metadata file but that didn't fix it:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.play.core.review']/class[@name='IReviewManager']" name="extends">Java.Lang.Object</attr> 
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.play.core.review.testing']/class[@name='FakeReviewManager']" name="extends">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

Here's the error I get:

```
...PlayCoreUpdateTest/PlayCoreUpdateTest.Android/InAppReviewService.cs(35,35): Error CS1061: 'FakeReviewManager' does not contain a definition for 'LaunchReviewFlow' and no accessible extension method 'LaunchReviewFlow' accepting a first argument of type 'FakeReviewManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (PlayCoreUpdateTest.Android)
```

[image: Screenshot of the error described above]
I know the magic happens in the generated api.xml file, so here's a [code dump](https://www.codedump.xyz/sql/YtwE1LiWHX5w6aq-) of it. In there I do see the `FakeReviewManager`, but I don't see the RequestReviewFlow, when it [should be there](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/review/testing/FakeReviewManager)

It's still a work in progress but those are the only remaining issues, here's the [GitHub code](https://github.com/saamerm/Xamarin-Google.Android.Play.Core.Review).
I watched [Jonathan Dick's video on creating Xamarin library bindings](https://youtu.be/NyqxScrnJKw?t=5813) and tried the [Microsoft FAQ options here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings) too

I know my functions in `InAppReviewService.cs` are correct because that's what the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#java) tell us to use, and it's what [we were using before](https://github.com/PatGet/XamarinPlayCoreUpdater/blob/master/PlayCoreUpdateTest/PlayCoreUpdateTest.Android/InAppReviewService.cs) for v1.10.

Update: I did notice there's an `api.xml.class-parse` file beside `api.xml`, that does contain the missing method `LaunchReviewFlow` inside the `FakeReviewManager` class. I'm trying to understand why it didn't show up in `api.xml`. Here's a dump for [that one](https://www.codedump.xyz/kotlin/Ytxl4Omx0M1Jrt4l). I did notice that in the `api.xml.class-parse` file, there are these lines

```
return="com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task&lt;java.lang.Void&gt;"
jni-return="Lcom/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task&lt;Ljava/lang/Void;&gt;;"
...
jni-signature="(Landroid/app/Activity;Lcom/google/android/play/core/review/ReviewInfo;)Lcom/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task;"
```

which that the v2.0 AAB file points to a play core tasks library even though it recommends pointing to the GMS version of Tasks
[image: Screenshot of above described]

To counter that, I tried to add variations of these lines, but none of that helped:

```
  <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.play.core.review.testing']/class[@name='FakeReviewManager']">
    <method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="launchReviewFlow" jni-signature="(Landroid/app/Activity;Lcom/google/android/play/core/review/ReviewInfo;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task;" bridge="false" native="false" return="com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task&lt;java.lang.Void&gt;" jni-return="Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task&lt;Ljava/lang/Void;&gt;;" static="false" synchronized="false" synthetic="false" visibility="public" return-not-null="true">
        <parameter name="p0" type="android.app.Activity" jni-type="Landroid/app/Activity;" not-null="true" />
        <parameter name="reviewInfo" type="com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo" jni-type="Lcom/google/android/play/core/review/ReviewInfo;" not-null="true" />
    </method>
    <method abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="requestReviewFlow" jni-signature="()Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task;" bridge="false" native="false" return="com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task&lt;com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo&gt;" jni-return="Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task&lt;Lcom/google/android/play/core/review/ReviewInfo;&gt;;" static="false" synchronized="false" synthetic="false" visibility="public" return-not-null="true" />
  </add-node>
```

Comment: @Jason any ideas on this one?